# Changing button color programmatically

Tags: javascript, button, label, dashboard

Is there a way to change the color of a button, or at least the color of the button label programmatically?
I can change the label itself with

```
document.getElementById("button").object.textElement.innerText = "newlabel";
```

But how to change the color?

Comment: +1 simply because i see no reason for someone voting this down.

Answer (score 47):

I have finally found a working code - try this:

```
document.getElementById("button").style.background='#000000';
```

Comment: document.getElementById("submit_button").style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen'; // this keeps the hover color change

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example using HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="this.style.color='#000000';
this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'" />
```

And here is an example using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("button").bgcolor="#Insert Color Here";
```

Comment: Sorry I put my reply to all posts two posts above, was to late yeterday :-(
So just to repeat, none of the proposals work, although the last one I do not understand so I did not try it.
Thanks for further hints.

Answer (score 6):

Probably best to change the className:

```
document.getElementById("button").className = 'button_color';
```

Then you add a buton style to the CSS where you can set the background color and anything else.

Comment: Thanks Nathan/DOK, none of these work. Simply nothing happens. Strange thing is that in CSS the color of the button is not defined at all. If I define it like color: #00cccc; then it changes (statically) the color of the label text..
Dashcode is a bit specific I guess, it is Apple-ized Javascript...
Any further idea?
Thanks
Zsolt

Comment: might be something to with the id of the button being button - perhaps change the id to 'submit_button' or something

Comment: I changed the id right away, I have paranoia from reserved words...but it does not work.

Comment: do you have the class set up in the CSS?

Comment: Yes
#my_button {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: default;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 185px;
    bottom: 175px;
    height: auto;
    left: 109px;
    color: rgb(0, 204, 204);
}

sorry, do not know how to do code highlight...
by default the color entry is not there, I added it by hand, and this changed the color of the text. I added it as #cc0000 but Daschode converts it into rgb()

Comment: The thing is that if I check the value of the document.getElementById("my_button").object.textElement.color then it picks up the newly set value, but this has no influence on visual appearance of the button itself, so it it either not .color or object.textElement.color.

Comment: you need to change the classname on document.getElementById("my_button") I don't think you need the object.textElement bit

Comment: sorry, I don't get it, can you point me to some URL where this is explained?

Comment: now I tried this
document.getElementById("my_button").setAttribute("class", "my_button2");
where the my_button2 has a different color then my_button, also does not work :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
use jquery :  $("#id").css("background","red");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Try this code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZEyJa)
You may want something like this

```
<button class="normal" id="myButton" 
        value="Hover" onmouseover="mouseOver()" 
        onmouseout="mouseOut()">Some text</button>
```

Then on your .js file enter this.Make sure your html is connected to your .js

```
var tag=document.getElementById("myButton");

function mouseOver() {
    tag.style.background="yellow";
};
function mouseOut() {
    tag.style.background="white";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign it to a class it should work:

```
<script>
  function changeClass(){
    document.getElementById('myButton').className = 'formatForButton';
  }
</script>

<style>
  .formatForButton {
    background-color:pink;
   }
</style>

<body>
  <input id='myButton' type=button class=none value='Change Color to pink' onclick='changeClass()'>
</body>
```

Comment: -1 for something which is *NOT* possible programatically! Well, OK, you /could/ create a new style element with an overridden "pink", but I doubt you even thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want bgcolor. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("button").bgcolor="#ffffff";
```

Here are a couple of demos that might help:

[Background Color](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/backgrou.htm)

[Background Color Changer](http://javascript.internet.com/image-effects/background-color-changer.html)