# How to change html button color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and I want when every time I click on the button changes its color to another color with JavaScript

Comment: Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819878/changing-button-color-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing button color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819878/changing-button-color-programmatically)

Comment: w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) has an article on how a button works and the functions of a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the solution your looking for is the following:

```
document.getElementById("buttonID").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("buttonID").style.backgroundColor = "yourColor";
}
```

This sample sets an onclick function to your button ID, and changes the background color. Of course, replace `yourColor` and `buttonID` with your appropriate needs.

Edit: I see that the question is a duplicate, and in the original question the answer you are looking for is further elaborated.

Answer (score 2):

you have to do : 
HTML:

```
<button id="btn_id">BUTTON</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("btn_id").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("btn_id").style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
}
```