# How to create a button that will change background color

Tags: javascript, html

I need help coding in HTML. I have tried many different ways of coding this button. The button is on the webpage now but will not change the background color of the web page.

```
     <html>
     <body>

     <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Blue</button>

    <script>

    function myFunction(){
    document.getElementByld("background").sytlecolor="blue";

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript change background color on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089414/javascript-change-background-color-on-click)

Comment: This question already have answers here on Stackoverflow, first you should google or search here on Stackoverflow and then post a question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing button color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819878/changing-button-color-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to go through [Javascript DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background="blue";   
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Blue</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function

```
function myFunction(){
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isBlue = false;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(isPurple){
        document.body.style.background= "white";
    } 
    else{
        document.body.style.background= "blue";
    }
    isBlue = !isBlue
})
```

This will not only change the background colour but will create a button that toggles it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors here:

1. You are selecting an element by id, but that element doesn't exists on your html.
2. Your javascript have a sintax error. (Missing closing brackets on your function.
3. You are using the property `sytlecolor` that doesn't exists (there's a typo on `style`, and even this way, `stylecolor` doesn't exists. Use `style.backgroundColor` instead.

Here's a working example:

```
<html>
<body id="background">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Blue</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.getElementByld("background").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you want to change the body background color, you don't need to put an id on it:

```
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Blue</button>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

````
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click to change color</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.body.style.background = "aqua";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>```

background is not a document object. It is an html dom object.
````

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in HTML Body

```
<a onclick="changecolor('navy')" id="navy">#0E2A36</a>
```

You can add customize color in CSS like

```
#navy{
    background:#0E2A36;
}
```

Then add JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changecolor(id) {
       document.body.style.background = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few spelling mistakes but this should explain

1.make the element a variable.
2. set that variable with .style.background = "blue"

spelling mistakes:

- sytle = style
- getElementByld = getElementById

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="background">
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Blue</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        //get the element
        const background = document.getElementById("background");
        // set it to blue
        background.style.background = "blue";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` of the specific element whose background you want to change

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background='green'
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button type="button" 
  onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background='green'">
  Click for green backgournd
  </button>
  <br />
  <br /><br />
  
  Another way to do from text box Just for your reference
  <br />
  <input style="width:100%" type="text" id="txtColorBox" placeholder="enter color name and click button"/>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" 
  onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background=document.getElementById('txtColorBox').value">
  Click for green backgournd
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with

```
//On top goes the head
<button type="button">Blue</button>
```

And then I would create a JS file

```
var button=document.querySelector('button'),
    body  =document.querySelector('body');

button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
});
```

That should turn the background blue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to this with vanilla javascript and the second is jQuery.

In your case, you are not using jQuery. So the solution is vanilla javascript.

```
function myFunction(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor="green";
}

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Blue</button> //Change web bg
```

if you need to change the button background. Pass the current pointer.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)"> Blue</button> //Change buttion bg
```

`bg => background`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could do something like so:

```js
document.getElementById('buttonColor').addEventListener('click', () => 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <button id="buttonColor">Change Color</button>
</body>
</html>
```