# Change the colour of the button dependently on condition with vanilla js/css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the color of the button dependently on some condition.

In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
if(condition){
    myelememt.background = "something"
}
```

But it should be checked and applied before the page is loaded.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing button color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819878/changing-button-color-programmatically)

Comment: _"But it should be checked and applied before the page is loaded."_. How can you change the colour of a button that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @Andy I meant that it should be resolved on the fly, but not after the page is loaded. It should not be visible for user

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it to apply the style before DOM paints, you can use `DOMContentLoaded` event, since this event fires as soon as the DOM nodes have finished loading, but before all assets, styles, etc... have been loaded.

Something like this should make it:

```js
const condition = true;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const button = document.querySelector('button');
  if (condition) button.style.background = 'red';
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>CLICK</button>
  </body>
</html>
```